# Problem with PHP Script to get Domain Age ( file_get_contents)

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Hi i have a Problem in php that i dont understand,

I made a **php script** to get the **domain age from specific domain form the waybackmachine** with file_get_contents

The Domains all in an array called domains and comes from an texfield from the user.

**The Script works fine** but only for the ***first domain in the array***, but for the second domain i get only strange values or nothing from the loop

but i dont know why, i see no mistake. And all domains in the array are correct.

Can anyone help me what i do wrong?

```
//Array with Domains
$domain = explode("\n",trim($_POST['url']));

// Print the Array for debugging
print_r($domain);



// count domains for the loop
$count = count($domain);
echo $count;

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

$content=file_get_contents('http://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url='.$domain[$i].'',FALSE, NULL, 1, 600);

//use the data from file_get_contents to calculate the age

preg_match('/\d+/', $content, $date); 
$startyear= substr($date[0], 0, -10);
$startmonth=  substr($date[0], 4, -8);
$actualyear= date("Y");


// calculate the year & month
$years= $actualyear- $startyear;
$month= 12-$startmonth;

//echo the Age

echo " <div style='font-size:20px;text-align:center;width:100%;height:5%;color:#25bb7f;
    font-weight: bold;'> $domain[$i]: $years Jahre und $month Monate </div>"; 

}
```

Comment: Hi, maybe you need to use `preg_match_all()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the URL decoding and encoding. The domains that you pass to `'http://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url='` have to be fully encoded.
See below how to accomplish this...

```
//Array with Domains
$domain = explode("\n",trim($_POST['url']));


# url encode all the urls/domains.
$domain = array_map(function($domain){ return urlencode($domain); }, $domain);

// Print the Array for debugging
print_r($domain);



// count domains for the loop
$count = count($domain);
echo $count;

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

$content=file_get_contents('http://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url='.$domain[$i].'',FALSE, NULL, 1, 600);

//use the data from file_get_contents to calculate the age

preg_match('/\d+/', $content, $date); 
$startyear= substr($date[0], 0, -10);
$startmonth=  substr($date[0], 4, -8);
$actualyear= date("Y");


// calculate the year & month
$years= $actualyear- $startyear;
$month= 12-$startmonth;

//echo the Age

$domainNonEncoded = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($domain[$i])); # get the decoded url

echo " <div style='font-size:20px;text-align:center;width:100%;height:5%;color:#25bb7f;
    font-weight: bold;'> {$domainNonEncoded}: $years Jahre und $month Monate </div>"; 

}
```

Comment: Thank you , that solve the problem. Now i get the correct data!

Comment: that is because the domain name was urlencoded. Look at my answer again, I have edited it to solve your second problem.

Comment: note i just edited it again to add the `htmlspecialchars` function. this basically helps with proper browser output by escaping some certain entity characters.

Comment: Thanks marvin, i searched to long for the right solution and dont know whats the problem :D

Comment: glad I could help.